# Move script to appear just under <body> when you cannot access HTML directly

Tags: jquery

I would like to move a custom script for Google Tag Manager to appear just under the open  tag. I cannot access the HTML directly to place something just below the opening body tag. Is there a script that would allow me to add the following just below the opening tag?

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<noscript><iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-TJ53BS"
height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-TJ53BS');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

So for example:

```
<body>
Some HTML and scripts are here
</body>
```

I would like the Google Tag Manager code to go just below

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Yes, this is possible but where will your script to add this script run?  There is likely no point to doing this if you have the script adding this script in the footer of your site.

Comment: This is the requirement by Google Tag Manager, it needs to be placed at to top of the body. I tried simply placing it within the body and it is not working, Google said it needs to be placed at the top of the body just under <body>

Comment: I'm not questioning the requirement, I'm saying that what you are asking for likely doesn't matter because the script that would insert this script is likely only running after the tag manager script would be finished if it were placed correctly.  You need to get access to modify your HTML to do this properly.

Comment: I cannot access the HTML, this is how the product was created. I can only add things by placing things in the head and footer. If i want something placed on a particular page I have to add a script that says to add this html to this page.

Comment: So, you do have access to the `<head>`?  Put your script to add this iframe and what not there.  Really, you can skip the `<noscript>` part... it's just for analytics, tracking those who have JS disabled.  Paste the rest directly in.